# How to detect milk spillage or milk boil?

Tags: electrical-engineering, design

In my country we generally boil milk before we drink. Often the milk heats up and spills from the pot. I want to detect milk boil before it spills off.I am thinking of a thermal camera solution that reads the temperature of liquid, but again it should be small enough to fit beside the gas stove. I have knowledge of python and arduino.

Please give me some ideas which works without physically touching the milk.

Comment: An optical sensor?

Comment: Tell us about your control scheme generally. Turn of stove when milk is at X °C? Or something more involved? How do you handle residual heat of stove (if any)?

Comment: @mart no I just want to raise alarm before milk boils. No need to control heat.

Comment: Waterproof temperature  sensor seems ideal . It goes inside the pot with the milk but I want to look into other possibility so we don't have to touch the milk.